# Looking for the grammar terms to describe the components of a question

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Questions like these:

- "How do I increase productivity in my organization?"
- "How do I increase pro-social behavior in my community?"

I want to say that in all of these questions, the *second part* (e.g., "in my organization" or "in my community") is limiting the generality of the answer to the *first part* (e.g., "How do I increase productivity" or "How do I increase pro-social behavior"). In other words, I want to say that the answer to the *first part* of the sentence is dependent on the conditions of the *second part* .. so the answer is going to be relative, not in absolute terms.

What is the grammatical term for the *first part* and the *second part* of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably talking about theme and rheme. Those are not purely grammar terms, they rather concern the communicative structure of a statement. "In my organization" is rheme in your examples.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Sergio! This seems like a possible answer. To make a better answer, it would help to provide a source or two for your claim via a link, resource title, and/or a quote. Well-researched answers show that there's a basis for *theme* (which most people have probably heard of) and *rheme* (which someone might never have heard of).